# Angular ng-repeat inside directive view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to do a ng-repeat inside the view returned by a directive.
Here is my template defined in templateUrl

```
<div class="outside">
    <div class"inside" ng-repeat="copas as cup">
        {{ cup.nombre }}
        cupcakes.nombre
        {{ cup }}
        cupcakes
    </div>
    {{ copas[0].nombre }}
    {{ copas }}
</div>
```

The content inside "inside" class is empty, while the content at the bottom of outside class is correct.
What am I missing?
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `cup in copas` for your ngRepeat expression:

```
<div class="outside">
    <div class"inside" ng-repeat="cup in copas">
        {{ cup.nombre }}
        cupcakes.nombre
        {{ cup }}
        cupcakes
    </div>
    {{ copas[0].nombre }}
    {{ copas }}
</div>
```